studio 24.04 installed. Tried update via 'updates available' button - failed
studio 24.04 installed (and working well). Tried update via 'updates available' button - failed with:
Dependency resolution failed: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntustudio-audio-core: Depends: ubuntustudio-pipewire-config but it is not going to be installed or ubuntustudio-pulseaudio-config but it is not going to be installed


So, I'm not a linux techy. What does the above message mean? And how to resolve?
Thanks

I'd suggest running sudo apt update & ensure you have no warnings, errors or missing lines in the output (alternatively look at your sources), as looking for one of those packages I can see it; ie. ubuntustudio-pipewire-config | 24.04.26 | noble/universe    | all where Ubuntu Studio has universe enabled by default, and your mention of Studio 24.04 implies Ubuntu Studio to me, but do you mean something else?

Did as you suggest. No errors, but I did notice that none of the original 3 items appear in the list. Likewise when getting the available updates none are listed. So why does the update fail?

Do you have universe enabled; it is default for Ubuntu Studio & flavor ISOs, but as stated I don't know what you're running as your question was unclear, thus you may not have it enabled.  Your question reads as a source issue, so check your sources.

It's unclear what "none of the original 3 items appear in the list" is supposed to mean. What are the "original 3 items" supposed to be?

Ok. I can confirm:

Ok, I can confirm it is ubuntu studio 24.04. All sources are selected (4 of them). The original 3 items are shown in original question: ubuntustudio-audio-core, ubuntustudio-pipewire-config, ubuntustudio-pulseaudio-config. None of the (many) updates  work giving the error message shown in the original question. Don't know what else I can tell you.

I'll suggest you read the whole of your messages; as messages should have included more than the two you pasted.  Usually the error message is further up the actual report, with a summary detail provided later, and it appears you've provided only the summary to me.   For best results; provide both command and all output - ie. what you actually see, as we're limited to details you provide.

Well, all I can say is many many thanks to (all) replies. After research on the apt command (which I've never used!), I executed apt install -f and this did indeed resolve the problem. My system seems to be 100% now - updates worked.

Well done for solving it @MikeW

This question is similar to: "but it is not going to be installed" Nightmare. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
